# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Links Not working on facebook

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using dynamic links for creating links and share it from my app to social media platforms, I tried to share on WhatsApp and messager and it's working great no problems.

The only exception when trying to open a link from Facebook, it opens the InAppBrowser first then opening the play store instead of my app!!!

If there any tweaks or workarounds for this issue please share it here as all the app marketing campings will depend on Facebook.

I don't know what code to put it here as Facebook is the only exception here!

**Anyway, here's the code for sharing and initiate:**

```dart
class ShareBloc extends Bloc<ShareEvent, ShareState> {

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigateKey;

  ShareBloc(this.navigateKey): assert(navigateKey != null);

  @override
  ShareState get initialState => ShareInitial();

  @override
  Stream<ShareState> mapEventToState(
    ShareEvent event,
  ) async* {

    if ( event is OnDynamicLinkInitial ) {


      final PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
      final Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData?.link;

      if ( deepLink != null ) {
        print(deepLink.path);
        navigateKey.currentState.pushNamed(SearchPage.routeName);
      }

      FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) async {
          final Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData?.link;

          if (deepLink != null) {
            print(deepLink.path);
            navigateKey.currentState.pushNamed(SearchPage.routeName);
          }
        },
        onError: (OnLinkErrorException error) async {
          print("ERR DeepLink: $error");
        }
      );
    }


    if ( event is ShareOnSocial ) {
      try {
        yield ShareLoading();
        final DynamicLinkParameters dynamicLinkParameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
          uriPrefix: 'http://xxx.page.link', 
          link: Uri.parse('https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/xxx/${event.post.id}'),
          androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
            packageName: 'com.xxx.xxx',
            minimumVersion: 17,
          ),
          dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
            shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
          ),
          socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
            title: event.post.title,
            // description: event.post.excerpt,
            imageUrl: Uri.parse(event.post.image)
          ),
          navigationInfoParameters: NavigationInfoParameters(
            forcedRedirectEnabled: true
          )
        );

        final shortDynamicLink = await dynamicLinkParameters.buildShortLink();
        final Uri shortUrl = shortDynamicLink.shortUrl;

        await Share.share(
          "${event.post.title} $shortUrl",
          subject: event.post.title,
        );

        yield ShareSuccess();
      } catch (e) {
        yield ShareFailure();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it? I have the same issue.

Comment: There's no solution for it, it's a bug from Google and you have to wait until they fix it or you go with another package such as uni_links flutter which I have done and it works great.

Comment: the uni_links packages you could check it from here: https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links

Answer (score 1):

I got few resources

Resources:

https://medium.com/dev-genius/firebase-flutter-dynamic-links-step-by-step-guide-630402ee729b

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links

Firebase Setup:
Setup `app.domain.com` in the firebase dynamic link section with TXT DNS change provided.

Use dynamically generated links from flutter code itself so no need to add any links in the firebase dashboard.

Code

Make sure to use the latest packages:

Pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.7.0+1
```

Info.plist

```html
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
    <string>https://app.yourdomain.com</string>
</array>
```